# Vim syntax issue with #if 1

Tags: c, vim

When I'm using #if 0, #else and #endif preprocessor to comment out my code, vim is showing the syntax properly. But if I use the sequence like this #if 1, #else and #endif vim is supposed to show the code between #else and #endif as commented, but it's not. My vim version is 7.2.411. I'm using these in lot of places in my code and sometimes get confused because no highlight is there. Is there a way to enable this. Thanks for the help.

eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
#if 1
    printf("inside #if 1\n");
#else
    printf("inside #else\n"); // <-- This part should appear in commented syntax
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot repro with vim 7.3.  Did you try `#if 42` instead of `#if 1`?

Comment: I tried. The same is happening. One more update I'm using CentOS 6.2

Comment: same here, works fine in Vim 7.4. Perhaps you need to upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to upgrade to vim 7.3+, or at least update your syntax file for C.  The first few lines of my $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim (for vim 7.3) are

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: C
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last Change:  2012 May 03
```

Using the example under `:help synID()`, I tried

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

and get "cCppInElse2".  Probably you will get something different.

The usual advice when overriding a default syntax file (or other vim script) is to put it in your own vimfiles directory.  I make an exception when the new file is part of a more recent standard distribution:  I *do* want it to be replaced when I upgrade to some future version of vim.

Comment: thanks.. The above command in my vim returned "cInclude". Anyhow I updated my vim to 7.4. Here it's fine and I'm getting the proper syntax highlight. Never thought that it was because of older version ;)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using

```
#if 1
printf("inside #if 1\n");   //This will work always and this is same as if(1){statement;}
#else
printf("inside #else\n");  //This part will never come
```

Because '#if 1' will always be true.

Comment: Yes, and I believe they are asking why the part after `#else` is not shown as “commented out” in vim.

Comment: @RahulKT: There's no issue with preprocessor. Only problem is vim is not giving me the commented syntax.